# Unable to remove Chrome extensions pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm

Tags: google-chrome

I keep deleting the `pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm` directory from AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions, but every time I start up chrome it reappears, full of files and all. `pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm` is the only directory in this path as I haven't installed any other extensions.

Even though the `pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm` is present at the aforementioned path, when I navigate to the Extensions page through Three Dots > More Tools > Extensions, I do not see any extensions there. This is concerning.

Why does this folder keep reappearing and how can I get rid of it permanently? The only thing I've found by searching on the web is something about a trojan, which is definitely not reassuring.

Comment: It's a built-in Chrome Media router extension, you can see it by running Chrome with `--show-component-extension-options` command line switch.

Answer (score 2):

It is Google Chromecast. As per the Chrome Extension IDs page